# Stop rails url_helper from requesting a lot of unnecessary objects from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I'm creating a large xml output using rails and there are a lot of urls generated by rails. There are so called items and enclosures. Every item may have one enclosure. So I'm using has_one and belongs_to relation in my model.

I'm using

```
enclosure_url(item.enclosure, format: :json)
```

for generating the url.

What I expect: Rails should generate the url based on the id which is stored in the items table.

What now happens is, that rails is fetching each single enclosure from the database which is slowing down my system.

```
Enclosure Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "enclosures".* FROM "enclosures" WHERE "enclosures"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11107]]
Enclosure Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "enclosures".* FROM "enclosures" WHERE "enclosures"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11108]]
Enclosure Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "enclosures".* FROM "enclosures" WHERE "enclosures"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11109]]
Enclosure Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "enclosures".* FROM "enclosures" WHERE "enclosures"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11110]]
Enclosure Load (6.8ms)  SELECT  "enclosures".* FROM "enclosures" WHERE "enclosures"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11111]]
```

Is there any trick stopping rails doing this or do I have to generate my url myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO you have two options:

1) Use [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) to load all `enclosures` in one query:

```
@items = Item.where(...).includes(:enclosure)
```

2) Pass the `id` of the `enclosure` to the url builder instead of the object:

```
enclosure_url(id: item.enclosure_id)
```

I would prefer the first option, because it ensures that the object you are linking to actually exists.